# Hibernate:Difference between setting the Id directly in the bean or calling the load() or get() method?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

Following is an example of load:-

```
Stock stock = (Stock)session.load(Stock.class, new Integer(2));
           StockTransaction stockTransactions = new StockTransaction();
           //set stockTransactions detail
           stockTransactions.setStock(stock);        
           session.save(stockTransactions);
```

What is the difference if i directely set the id in like:-

```
Stock stock =new Stock();
stock.setId(2);
 StockTransaction stockTransactions = new StockTransaction();
               //set stockTransactions detail
               stockTransactions.setStock(stock);        
               session.save(stockTransactions);
```

As i already know the Id of the stock table. Y call the load or get?

Comment: The only difference is that when using transient entity, you can get FK violation (if the identifier is incorrect) or the entity can be non-willingly persisted if the *CASCADE* association parameter is set. Also loading the entity is a bit nicer because it will execute LOAD event handlers, which might be a big deal if you have some security implemented in that way.

Comment: So seems like there is no big difference.. But wouldn't loading it first and then setting would have an effect on performance?

Comment: Performance depends on the use-case. Usually you need to get the entity anyway (e.g. validating its existence and ownership). When the use-case concerns only a constant number of associated entities, I wouldn't care that much about performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the difference ...

Your first sample of code fetches object from database, thus loaded object will be in persisted state. Your second sample will try to save `StockTransaction` with **completely new** `Stock`. This may lead to primary key errors (if stock id is unique) or duplicate entries. You should base the choice of which way to use on your requirements. If you need `StockTransaction` with existing `Stock` (I assume this is your case as you wrote that you know ID) - you should load it from database first.

> Y call the load or get?

[Session.load()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#load%28java.lang.Class,%20java.io.Serializable%29) will return a proxy with empty fields, if there is no such object (with such id) in the database.

[Session.get()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#get%28java.lang.Class,%20java.io.Serializable%29) will return null if there is no object with such id.

Which one to use is up to you and your task. Personally I prefer `get()`.

Comment: I didn't get this when you say: This may lead to primary key errors (if stock id is unique) or duplicate entries

Comment: @Dennis Consider the following situation [prerequisite - your code as is] - You have no unique checks for `Stock.id` and trying code from second quotation. This will lead to creation of `Stock` with id `2` even if it already exists. Other situation - you have unique constraint. In that case DB won't let to save `StockTransaction` because there is `Stock` with id `2` **already** in the related table. Feel free to ask if it doesn't clear yet, I'll be glad to explain.

Comment: and i am saving StockTransaction not Stack so how would this lead to creation of Stock?:  This will lead to creation of Stock with id 2 even if it already exists.

Comment: @Dennis This will lead to creation of another `Stock` because you're passing brand new `Stock` object to `StockTransaction`.

Comment: But we are not calling save on Stock but on StockTransation so hibernate will only save StockTransation not Stock.

Comment: @Dennis That depends on mapping details. Sometimes, this is true, but not always.

Comment: Oh i didn't knew that. Thanks for the info. Can you share the property name to set true in case of saving Stock also? My entities are annotation based

Comment: @Dennis http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-cascade-example-save-update-delete-and-delete-orphan/ - here you can find decent information on this. Although the examples are in XML mapping, for annotation-based you should have the same properties.

Answer (score 1):

The object create will be in persistent State.

```
 Stock stock = (Stock)session.load(Stock.class, new Integer(2));
```

The object create will be in transient State.

```
Stock stock =new Stock();
stock.setId(2);
```

**Transient State:**

> A New instance of  a persistent class which is not associated with a Session, has no representation in the database and no identifier value is considered transient by Hibernate:

**Persistent State:**

> A persistent instance has a representation in the database , an identifier value and is associated with a Session. You can make a transient instance persistent by associating it with a Session:

REFERENCE

http://www.dineshonjava.com/p/transient-persistent-and-detached.html#.U4LKlHakrlc

Comment: Ok, so any advantages i get making this persistent? I mean if i change any other column value of stock and call save on StockTransaction would the change in Stock be saved also?

Comment: Does your above code worked because directly setting ID will give you org.hibernate.transientobjectexception

Comment: check this out http://www.roseindia.net/hibernate/hibernate4/org_hibernate_transientobjectexception.shtml

Comment: Yes, it works the ID being the PK. It won't work for other columns just like the example you gave. So m not sure what's the use of calling the load or get

Comment: from my point of view, load or get also help you to check existence of your data.

Comment: Like examining other fields? stock.getFoo().equals("something")? Or any other case?

Answer (score 1):

To correctly synchronize the object state with database the objects needs to be *managed* by hibernate ( `aka` associated with persistence context). At the flush time it is the content of persistence context which decides what is going to be flushed to database and then committed. Apart from that relationships are always created between persistent entities. The persistent nature may be explicit (by calling any of the appropriate API method - save,update,merge etc in native hibernate or their JPA counterparts)
or implicit (due to *cascade* property or by virtue of being loaded by appropriate API call like load, get etc). Another reason for the entities being persistent is write-behind transactional nature where you can keep modifying the state of object and the delta is propagated to the database in the end at transaction commit time or explicit flush. In an object graph what needs to be propagated to the database depends upon what objects are managed or persistent (both terms used interchangeably most of the time). There is a concept of detached objects ( objects which have their database identifier set but are no guaranteed to
represent the actual state in database. Actually any data can be potentially stale outside transaction). For these too you have option of reattaching / merging to persistence context ( in native hibernate) or merging (in JPA ).

Also while creating bidirectional relationships - another concept needs to be taken into consideration - inverse. The inverse side is not responsible for relationship creation, so just setting the relation from inverse side will not result in the relationship being persisted in database via foreign key.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's not that common if you only plan on saving the child entity (StockTransaction) than both methods will yield the same result. You will get the child persisted and after a flush the parent is going to be attached to the current Session.

I created a test on [GitHub](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/vladmihalcea.wordpress.com/blob/master/hibernate-facts/src/test/java/com/vladmihalcea/HibernateSaveIdOnlyEntityTest.java):

```
final Long parentId = cleanAndSaveParent();
transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallback<Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void doInTransaction(TransactionStatus transactionStatus) {
            SetParent idOnlyParent = new SetParent();
            idOnlyParent.setId(parentId);
            SetChild newChild = new SetChild();
            newChild.setName("new");
            newChild.setParent(idOnlyParent);
            entityManager.persist(newChild);
            entityManager.flush();
            SetChild otherChild = new SetChild();
            otherChild.setName("Other");
            idOnlyParent.addChild(otherChild);
            entityManager.flush();
            assertEquals(1, idOnlyParent.getChildren().size());
            return null;
        }
    });

    transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallback<Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void doInTransaction(TransactionStatus transactionStatus) {
            SetParent parent = entityManager.find(SetParent.class, parentId);
            assertEquals(3, parent.getChildren().size());
            return null;
        }
    });
```

When flush() is called the newChild object will become attached to the current Session. But the parent isn't going to be attached, so changes to the parent side won't be synchronized at all.

If the parent was fetched from the DB, then changed to the parent would have been "dirty checked" and synchronized at flush time.

Even if it's possible to do it, it's not really advisable. It may get you the false impression that you are still working with an attached parent entity, while you only get a transient parent.

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain it this way: your question is reasonable and there is a clear answer - use **`load()`**. Why? In general we do have three ways how to obtain an instnace by ID.

1) One, extreme, and in fact inappropriate, mention just for complexity, would be to use a query, e.g. with restriction on ID. This query must hit DB...

2) Then, we have `get()`, which was intended as the most common way how to get item by ID. It always hits DB because its **contract** says ([get](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#get%28java.lang.Class,%20java.io.Serializable%29)):

> Return the persistent instance of the given entity class with the given identifier, or **null** if there is no such persistent instance

So, to be sure that object exists or not, DB must be hit.

3) Finally, for a reason, there is a third **contract** - `load()`. It will never hit DB to check if there is such an item *(with provided ID)*: [load()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#load%28java.lang.Class,%20java.io.Serializable%29):

> Return the persistent instance of the given entity class with the given identifier, assuming that the instance exists.

The Contract here expects that. On the other hand, this convention is there to help us to solve situation described in this query

If we do have reference ID, and we know that it does exist we shouuld use the `load()`. It will create a proxy instance - **with provided ID** and during the INSERT or UPDATE of that root/holder entity, the proxy ID will be used to create correct SQL Statement.

**Summary:** `get()` and `load()` are there for us for a reason. They were designed to support different scenarios. For CRUD operations of the root entity, we should recieve it by `get()`, to be sure that upper layers asked for existing ID. The use case for `load()` is when we do have ID and just want to persist that...

See also:

- [Different between session.get() and session.load()](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/different-between-session-get-and-session-load/)
- NHibernate – [The difference between Get, Load and querying by id](http://ayende.com/blog/3988/nhibernate-the-difference-between-get-load-and-querying-by-id)