# Why Id setter is protected in NHibernate base entity?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm

What is the purpose to mark Id setter is protected in NHibernate base entity?

```
public abstract class Entity<T>
{
    public virtual T Id { get; protected set; }
}
```

Now I want to set this **Id** in my service layer but I cannot due to its access-level because setter is `protected`.

Can I remove "`protected`" modifier from my setter? Or, If I remove "`protected`" does it break any rule?

Comment: Have you tried setting it to public and seeing what happens?

Comment: @Phill - No, I didn't remove protected yet. First I just want to know what will be the effect if I remove protected.

Comment: TRY IT. Seriously, you're a programmer, try it and find out, learn.

Comment: @Phill - Of course I am. But the first thing is understanding, what we are doing and why we are doing.

Comment: Another point: NHibernate has NO "base entity" - NHibernate does not provide such a class. That is your class and you must design it to fit your needs.

Comment: @OskarBerggren - I knew it already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about it this way:

> Having an `ID` is enough to get an **instance**. It is read-only by design, because the persisted *(already stored)* entity, can be **just** received, loaded by ORM tool from DB.

And there are few ways how to get such instance. And these methods are there again for us - **by design**.

1) `session.Load<TEntity>(id)` - will return a proxy, representing the instance. Until any of its properties is touched, no DB call is executed

2) `session.Get<TEntity>(id)` - will immediately call the DB - and return NULL if no such record for passed ID exists. If there is any record, it is loaded into session.. ready for further processing

More details:

#### [NHibernate difference between Query<T>, Get<T> and Load<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37178455/1679310)

Comment: Still my question is same. How can I set this Id property in my service layer? Is there a way?

Comment: Yes you can. If you prefer that.. it is not prohibited. With that approach, when you do not firstly load object from DB... you are in fact working with a `Detached object`, which is **absolutely ok and supported**: [9.4.2. Updating detached objects](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-updating-detached) ... so change your ID to **public**.. if you like. But if you ask "why readonly" ... I tried to answer ;) BTW - I always load existing object, and bind to it... ;)

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation.

Comment: Glad if that helped a bit ;) Enjoy NHibernate!