# nhibernate is it possible to add child object by ID

Tags: nhibernate

given the classes

```
public class Board {
       public int Id { get; set; }

       public int Player1Id { get; set; }
       public Player player1 { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Player {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

In EF if I wanted to assign a player (that is already in the db) to a board we could do:

```
var board = new Board {
     Player1Id = 2 //given that the player ID in the db is 2
}
```

This would create the association without requiring to get the player entity out of the database and directly assign it.  So when next getting the board and player it would return the player object from the db.

Is it possible to do the same with NHibnerate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way (after all tries) .. would be to use **`Load<TEntity>(id)`**.

[9.2. Loading an object](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-loading)

small cite:

> ...`Load()` returns an object that is an uninitialized proxy and
>   **does not actually hit the database** until you invoke a method of the object. This behaviour is **very useful if you wish to create an
>   association to an object without actually loading it** from the
>   database...

In a nutshell: this is the native NHibernate support to convert ID to "proxy instance" and provide a mapped reference.

*There could be some custom encapsulation.. E.g. upper (business layer) `IReadFacade<out TEntity>` with some `LoadById(id)`...*

Also check: [NHibernate difference between Query<T>, Get<T> and Load<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37178455/1679310)