# NHibernate, Add parent if not exists when adding child

Tags: c#, sqlite, nhibernate

I'm using this code to determine if it should create a parent or if the parent already exists:

```
var id = 1;
var parent = Session.Get<Parent>(id);

if (parent == null)
  parent = new Parent();

var child = new Child();

child.Parent = parent;
parent.Children.Add(child);

Session.Save(parent);
```

Right now this seems very inefficient, this method queries the database with 3 separate sql queries everytime when a child is added:

1. Get parent based on id
2. Insert child
3. Insert/update parent (depending if the parent did exist)

Could i do this in a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two scenarios in fact.

In the first case, when we really do **not know**, if there is a parent with provided **id** - there's no other way. Such solution will always require *so many* sql statements.. to find out if there is a parent and insert if not.

In the second scenario, if we **do know** that there is a parent in DB (with provided **id**) - we can make it more efficient with a built in support: `Load<Parent>(id)`

#### [9.2. Loading an object](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-loading)

> ...  `Load()` returns an object that is an uninitialized proxy and
>   does **not actually hit the database** until you invoke a method of the
>   object...

Get more details here:

#### [NHibernate difference between Query<T>, Get<T> and Load<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37178455)

Answer (score 2):

Given that you are in a regular business logic development, I wouldn't mind these queries.

`Get` is quite fast, because it usually performs a lookup by primary key, which usually is a clustered index (don't know about SQLite).

Existing parents need to be found to be linked anyway. You can postpone the actual query by using `Load`, but in my experience you need the parent anyway.

Updating the parent may be unnecessary. What does it update? Is there a missing inverse-mapping?

If you are doing the whole thing for a lot of records (not only one), you may consider other options. (Batches, pre-fetching, Futures, whatever.)

If you think that you need a highly optimized implementation for exactly this code, you should consider to avoid using an ORM and implement it in plain SQL (and recheck if it would really use less queries). Writing object oriented code requires having objects in memory which sometimes requires getting data from the database that wouldn't be required in a highly optimized implementation.